# Implementing a AutoComplete dropdown in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here is my HTML

```
<h2>Please Enter the Value in the Box(click on the desired value)</h2>
<input id='value' type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="country" />
<div id="dropdown">
    <select name="list" id="list"></select>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript

```
var arr = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua &amp; Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cruise Ship","Cuba","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kuwait","Kyrgyz Republic","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Namibia","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Satellite","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","South Africa","South Korea","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts &amp; Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","St. Lucia","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad &amp; Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks &amp; Caicos","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];
var input = document.getElementById('value');
var optionsVal = document.getElementById('list');

input.addEventListener('keyup', show);
optionsVal.onclick = function(){
    setVal(this);
};

//shows the list
function show(){
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
    dropdown.style.display = 'none';

    optionsVal.options.length = 0;

    if(input.value){
        dropdown.style.display = 'block';
        optionsVal.size = 3;
        var textCountry = input.value;

        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i].indexOf(textCountry) !== -1){
                //addvalue
                addValue(arr[i],arr[i]);

            }
        }

    }
}

function addValue(text,val){
    var createOptions = document.createElement('option');
    optionsVal.appendChild(createOptions);
    createOptions.text = text;
    createOptions.value = val;
}

//Settin the value in the box by firing the click event
function setVal(selectedVal){
    input.value = selectedVal.value;
    document.getElementById('dropdown').style.display='none';
}
```

This issue i am running into is the logic involved when checking for the input value and showing the values in the dropdown. For example if i type in 'u' only countries 'Anguilla, Antigua' show up instead of any country with 'u' in it. I know the issue lies where i am checking for indexOf, but i am stuck here.

Also how can i keep the dropdown size dynamic to the values found? Your feedback would be great in improving the overall problem too

Comment: can you attach a jsFiddle please

Comment: for me there are all expected countries in the dropdown

Comment: JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e6220t92/

Comment: Fiddle seems to be working fine in IE11.

Comment: When the final goal is the autocomplete and not the implementation via JS you may take a look [`datalist`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) (html-only solution)

Comment: @Dr.Molle yes i would have used the jquery widget  or datalist as you mentioned but wanted to see what it would be to implement without external libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a `match` instead of `indexOf`? 
Added benefit this will search case insensitive. http://jsfiddle.net/e6220t92/2/. Fiddle also has an attempt to increase the size of the select box.

```
    //CODE
    var testableRegExp = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(textCountry),"i");
    if (arr[i].match(testableRegExp ) )
    {
       //logic
    }
    //CODE

//Use this function to replace potential characters that could break the regex
RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};
```

Comment: thnxs for the response, you are right match is much better solution

Comment: Although this is an old question, recommending regex is not the best strategy. Using a combination of .toLowerCase().indexOf() is orders of magnitude faster than .match(/.../i): https://jsbench.me/grjq2l4vhr/1

Comment: depends on how long the list is, no?  the js fiddle seems pretty fast

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to resize the option list after filtering the input elements.

You can do this by removing the line:

```
optionsVal.size = 3;
```

And changing the for loop that filters options to add a resize that is the same size as the filtered results:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].indexOf(textCountry) !== -1){
        //addvalue
        addValue(arr[i],arr[i]);
        optionsVal.size = optionsVal.options.length;
    }
}
```

It's a little ugly if there are no options, and really long when you enter something like just like an "a", but I think this is what you are after.

Changed show() function:

```
//shows the list
function show(){
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
    dropdown.style.display = 'none';

optionsVal.options.length = 0;

if(input.value){
    dropdown.style.display = 'block';
    var textCountry = input.value;

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i].indexOf(textCountry) !== -1){
            //addvalue
            addValue(arr[i],arr[i]);
            optionsVal.size = optionsVal.options.length;
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: thnxs, makes sense to add to size after invoking the function